# Server side pagination with single document string array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to do server side pagination for a single document that contains a `blacklistGroup: [String]` field

```
  "blacklistGroup": [
    "5e99fd3aa506cf570056898d",
    "5e99fde5a506cf5700568991",
    "5e99fd64a506cf570056898e",
    "5e98c950f4fb3f63b4634e30",
    "5e99fd15a506cf570056898c",
    "5e99fda5a506cf570056898f",
    "5e99fdc7a506cf5700568990",
    "5e99fcf3a506cf570056898b",
    "5e98e90d85e69146f841d23a",
    "5e9867ff5e72550988820dd3",
    "5e98e8e785e69146f841d239"
  ]
```

I want it to limit 10 at a time. I'm basically looking for the equivalent to

```
     User.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
              .select("blacklistGroup")
              .populate("blacklistGroup", "username")
              .skip(10 * (req.query.currentPage - 1))
              .limit(10)
              .then(documents => {
```

but obviously not for multiple documents, but for the single document being queried. I'm currently passing the current page to the backend to retrieve that specific page's list of 10. Also it's important to return the username hence the `.populate` in example. I appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 3):

You could use slice on query followed by populate.

```
User.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
           .slice('blacklistGroup', [10 * (req.query.currentPage - 1), 10])
           .populate("blacklistGroup", "username");
```

You could also use aggregate with $slice and $lookup.

```
User.aggregate([
 {"$match":{"_id":req.params.id}},
 {"$project":{"blacklistGroup":{"$slice":["$blacklistGroup", 10 * (req.query.currentPage - 1), 10]}}},
 {"$lookup":{
   "from": usercollection,
   "localField": "blacklistGroup",
   "foreignField": "_id",
   "as": "blacklistGroup"
 }},
 {"$project":{"usernames":"$blacklistGroup.username"}}])
```

You could furthur enhance it using newer lookup version.

```
User.aggregate([
 {"$match":{"_id":req.params.id}},
 {"$lookup":{
  "from":usercollection,
  "let":{"blacklistGroup":{"$slice":["$blacklistGroup", 10 * (req.query.currentPage - 1), 10]}},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$_id","$$blacklistGroup"]}}},
    {"$project":{"username":1,"_id":0}}
  ],
  "as":"blacklistGroup"
}}]);
```

For the sake of completeness added the whole example

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    blacklistGroup: [{
      type: String,
      ref: 'Group'
    }]
  })
const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    content: String,
    username: String
  })
const User  = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'users');
const Group = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema, 'groups');
module.exports = {
    User, Group
  }

 User.findOne().slice("blacklistGroup", 3).populate("blacklistGroup", "username").exec((err, blacklistGroup) => {
      console.log("Populated blacklistGroup " + blacklistGroups);
    })
```

Also added Mongo Playground likn for example 2

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YP5l5Kz3sp8

Comment: Thanks for the examples. If I do the first example, then I get $slice must be an integer? Why is that? I added ```JSON.parse(req.query.currentPage)``` just in case, but it still returned that error. If I do the second example, it returns ```[ { _id: 5e9f1f056a16165270049abd, usernames: [] }``` There should be data returned. If I try the last one like so https://pastebin.com/48mmgQ1t I get ```Unrecognized parameter to $lookup: let```

Comment: Np - I have tested all the solutions - so the first two errors  are related to either mismatch in field name or type. For the first one you just need to make sure you are sending integer limits. For second one make sure you have correct user collection name (plural names) and the foreign field is `_id`. For the last one it could be that you are not on 3.6 mongodb veersion. Could you also add your mongoose schema and models ?

Comment: Regarding example 2, it might be that we have strings in the `blacklistGroup` but use ObjectIds for the `_id`. In that case the `$lookup`-stage will not match anything. If we are on lower than mongodb version 4.0, the schema might need to be changed to align the types of the two properties.

Comment: @abondoa - Agreed - Added an working mongoose example. Please make sure the types for both local and foreign fields match.

Comment: I'm using Cosmosdb and I think it's running on 3.6. I created a pastebin breakdown of my results including user schema.  https://pastebin.com/1PtW1ry7

Comment: Sorry it looks like limitation of cosmosdb. I don’t have cosmosdb to verify. For the second solution could you make sure your blacklistGroup are objectids instead of string because I believe _id is objectid. This is why look up match not returning any values. –

Comment: I don't believe blacklistGroup is an objectId as it's defined as ```blacklistGroup: [String]``` and looks like this in document https://postimg.cc/jnWprBG6 instead of this https://postimg.cc/jCQ3kHC3 I'm trying to get the first example working, but I don't understand why the slice error is happening since everything inside ```.slice``` is an integer. See example I made that also reflects a working blacklistgroup output too https://pastebin.com/YyX5sgAL

Comment: Sorry I have no idea why the first solution wont work. Have you tried directly passing the values something like `.slice('blacklistGroup', [0,2])` ?. If this works it means there are no issues with cosmodb. Also please let me know what mongoose version you are on.

Comment: ```User.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).slice('blacklistGroup', [0, 2]).then((res) => {``` outputs slice must be an integer.  I'm using ```mongoose@5.9.5```

Comment: I know it's not working yet, but I felt you earned it since the bounty was gonna expire lol

Comment: I think cosmosdb doesn't support slice. That's why I'm having that problem. Reference: https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/issues/151   Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for the bounty. I think the only solution left is to change your `blackListGroup` type from string array to object id array and use $lookup. Not sure if $slice aggregation operator is supported but I don't remember you received an error regarding slice when you tried lookup solution. I can rework the lookup solution to avoid slice if you run into same issue.

Comment: I now think slice is supported per this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36 so it must be something else causing the problem. Also you're right. Slice wasn't the error I was getting with $lookup. That error was ```Unrecognized parameter to $lookup: let``` maybe it has something to do with the ```$``` everywhere?

Comment: The new lookup looks like is not supported yet - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/35862181-add-support-for-latest-lookup-step-in-aggregation. I think you should try to change types.

Comment: Could you add `mongoose.set(‘debug’, true)` at the top of your mongoose code  and verify the generated query on the console  for first example ?

Comment: Thank you. The query generated by mongoose looks good. This looks like cosmos issue. Created https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/40296598-slice-projection-not-working-mongodb. Hopefully someone can get to it.

Comment: Ok. I also provided a sample screenshot of a findById() cmd without slice to show off the output data https://postimg.cc/dZ9tGDhH .

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this cannot be done using the `populate` function, instead you'll have to use aggregation:

```
User.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    _id: req.params.id
  }},
  {$unwind: '$blacklistGroup'},
  {$addFields:{
    blacklistGroupId: {$toObjectId: "$blacklistGroup"}
  }},
  {$lookup:{
    from: '<name of your blacklist collection>',
    localField: 'blacklistGroupId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'blacklistGroup'
  }},
  {$skip: 10 * (req.query.currentPage - 1)},
  {$limit: 10},
  {$group:{
    _id: '$_id',
    blacklistGroup: {$push: '$blacklistGroup.username'}
  }}
]).exec().then(documents => {
  //...
})
```

This will give you a single document that contains the `blacklistGroup` property that is an array of `username`s. You can remove the `$group`-stage to keep these as 10 separate documents.

Note that this requires version 4.0 mongo.

Comment: I changed the from:  to ```users```, but it returns a blank ```[]``` There should be data

Comment: It's might be that you have strings in your `blacklistGroup` but use ObjectIds for the `_id`. If you're on mongo version 4.0 you can use `$toObjectId`. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it's 3.6 according to cosmosdb. Also it doesn't seem to like $toObjectid ```{ MongoError: unknown operator: $toObjectId```. So it must be 3.6

Comment: For mongo 3.6 and older, there is no in-query conversion of types (as far as I know). You will need to change your data so that `_id` and the elements in `blacklistGroup` are the same - either string or ObjectId (I would suggest ObjectId).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the aggregate function and follow the steps,

```
$lookup:{
   "from": <usercollection>,
   "localField": "blacklistGroup",
   "foreignField": "_id",
   "as": "blacklistGroup"
 }
```

then,

```
$unwind: {
             path : <usercollection>,
         }
```

then,

```
$match: {
        ...
        }
```

your desired condition. after then do your use your limit function following the aggregate pattern.