# $PullAll across documents - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to remove entries of a listingId from a user's watchlist in my example. Each user collection has a watchlist string array where users can store the items they are watching.

**Sample Doc :**

```
 "watchlist": [
    "5ea8449842025217ccff6aec",
    "5ea844eb42025217ccff6aee",
    "5ea8452b42025217ccff6af1"
  ],
```

In order to maintain a clean database I'm creating an azure timer function to deploy every so often to find and remove watchlist items of listings that no longer exist anymore. There could be many users that have the same listing id entry in their watchlist. So I need to clean those up with regular checks.

**Query :**

```
Post.find({
  $and: [
    { watchlistCleaned: false },
    { auctionEndDateTime: { $lte: Date.now() } }
  ]
}).select("_id").then((res) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    console.log("res[i]")
    console.log(res[i]._id)


  //pretty sure this would remove the whole watchlist instead of one item so this wouldn't be ideal. 
  //It's needs to pull the items out on a multiple document scale

   // User.deleteMany({ _id: res[i]._id },{watchlist: {$in: res[i]}})

  }

})
```

**Desired Output :**

```
 { _id: 5ea84412048bf54164fe9983 }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea8449842025217ccff6aec }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea844c042025217ccff6aed }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea844eb42025217ccff6aee }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea844ed42025217ccff6aef }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea844ee42025217ccff6af0 }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea8452b42025217ccff6af1 }
 res[i]
 { _id: 5ea85daac6e12a10b09a75a5 }
```

Comment: what does this `res` has ? Does it have `_id`'s of watchlist items or `_id`'s of users ? Also what is this  `watchlistGroup` - Is your array name `watchlist` or `watchlistGroup` ?

Comment: I added res output above. The output represents the listings that haven't been ```watchlistCleaned``` or set to false so that it doesn't clean same listing twice. Watchlist group is a typo. I fixed it just now. My array, which is in each user document is called ```watchlist: [String]```

Comment: So `res` is a list of string/ids which needs to be removed from user's `watchlist` array ?

Comment: Correct. the res _ids are the listing ids that are inside some of the user documents because they added that listing to their watchlist. This is for cleanup of listings Ids for old listings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current code :

```
 User.deleteMany()
 /** Will actually delete docs from users collection, you need to use .update() or .findAndUpdate() to alter fields inside docs */
```

If `res` is an array of listings id's then you can do this :

```
Post.distinct("_id", { watchlistCleaned: false, auctionEndDateTime: { $lte: Date.now() } }).then((res) => {
  /** So `res` will be an array of unique `_id`'s of Post collection which matches given conditions */
  User.updateMany(
    { watchlist: { $in: res } }, /** get users who have listings ids  */
    {$pullAll : { watchlist : res } } /** pull all listing ids */
  );
});
```

Comment: I added your solution, but it's returning ```[4/28/2020 7:34:17 PM] (node:19304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to [string] failed for value "[{"$pullAll":["5ea84412048bf54164fe9983","5ea8449842025217ccff6aec","5ea844c042025217ccff6aed","5ea844eb42025217ccff6aee","5ea844ed42025217ccff6aef","5ea844ee42025217ccff6af0","5ea8452b42025217ccff6af1","5ea85daac6e12a10b09a75a5"]}]" at path "watchlist"```

Comment: @user6680 : my bad there is a typo, updated answer - try now..

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks so much! Any chance you can take a crack at this other post I made that's also related to manipulating string arrays in document. I've been stuck on it for over a week now. The current answers aren't supported by cosmosdb, which I'm using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290693/server-side-pagination-with-single-document-string-array-field

Comment: @user6680 : I've not worked cosmosDB, As far as I've worked on, I also used `slice` to do pagination on arrays, most of the answers are best suited nothing in my mind as of now, will post something over there if I find any..