# Mission delete all fluffy objects in array from MongoDb, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

one of my properties in the doc is a Array which is filled with nice fluffy object.
Now i want to wipe all objects which have a specific range -> qdate:20210225.

The db property is called weeks and looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250600",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250615",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "30"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250630",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "45"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250645",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "07",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250700",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "07",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250715",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "08",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250800",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "08",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250815",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "08",
            "30"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250830",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "08",
            "45"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102250845",
        "qdate": 20210225,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "09",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": "202102260900",
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
]
```

I can delete one of this fluffy objects but the others wont go.
I tried something like this in various combinations.

```
const company = await Company.updateMany(
    { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
    { $pullAll: [{ 'weeks.qdate': 20210225 }] },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );

 const company = await Company.updateMany(
    { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
    { $pullAll: [{ 'weeks': { $elemMatch: { qdate: 20210225 } } }] },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

Iam aware that from a query i can pull only one occurance , so i could just find one object with the fluffy value of qdate:20210225 , in order to get all i wrote an aggregate pipeline but there i cant delete the object entirely i can just replace the values.

Any good soul here to help me out?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485846/2282634

Comment: Thank you but this will not work, because he has [1,2,3] and i have [{},{},{}];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) will solve your problem:

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array **all** instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

The below code may help:

```
const company = await Company.updateMany(
  { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
  { $pull: { weeks: { qdate: 20210225 } } },
  ...
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks thats it.
Im sure i tried this also before but i see now that i get nModified:1 no matter how many items are deleted. I expected the n count higher.

When i checked the db now i saw that your proposed query worked.

Thanks